# Error after installing Json.Net and reference it in the project. Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, json.net, nuget, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to read data from a json file in WP8 and after installing nuget displays the following error:

error :

> Cannot resolve reference assemblies. Please check the reference assemblies. Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.

Could anyone tell me a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Add `System.Runtime.InteropServices` to your project references;

it's in the global assembly cache; the Add References dialog shows it under the ".NET" tab.

If this doesnt solve the problem following the directions [here](http://thounsell.co.uk/windows-phone/avoiding-reflection-adding-the-interopservices-library-to-the-wp7-sdk/) should allow you to remove the recursion that happens.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do this?
I tried adding clicking. "NET for Windows Phone" and added the reference, however the following error.

Comment: @EduardoAndrade I see, it looks like you need to manually remove the recursion.  See my edits.

Comment: I will try this and post the result here. Gracias!

Comment: @paqogomez, any luck?